# Kill process in swift

Tags: swift, process, macos-sierra, launch

I am trying to make a Mac application that will automatically close a code designated application running on the OS.  I am trying to use killall (like in Terminal).  Whenever I try to run the program, I get, "sysctl: unknown oid 'killall'".

Here's my code:

```
let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/sysctl"
    ///usr/sbin/sysctl
    task.arguments = ["killall","iTunes"]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
    print(output)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You missed a forward slash. Shouldn't it be `/usr/sbin/sysctl`?

Comment: You are correct.  But when I run it now, it states "sysctl: unknown oid 'killall".  I have updated the question to this new error.

Comment: @CodeDifferent What sbin file do I need in order to use killall?

Comment: sysctl is not the one to use for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you first read the `man` page for `sysctl` -- it's used to get and set kernel state. Does that sound like something you want?

The path to `killall` is `/usr/bin/killall`, which you can find from Terminal:

```
> which killall
/usr/bin/killall
```

Here's the full Swift code:

```
let pipe = Pipe()

let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/killall"
task.arguments = ["iTunes"]
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.standardError = pipe
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(output)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

my 2 cents:
You succeed in killing "iTunes" only if You Xcode App will run with SandoBox DISABLED[image]

All examples on stack overflow about Process are misleading as they call "ls" or "echo" that are always executed in system folders.